# Трафик между клиентами VPN в одной подсети

Tags: vpn

Всем доброго времени суток, нет русскоязычной информации по этому вопросу, прошу помочь разобраться: имеется 2008 R2 с SSTP сервером, удаленные и локальные клиенты VPN, вся настройка сервера стандартная без каких-либо особенностей. Локальная подсеть: 192.168.0.0/24, VPN: 172.16.1.0/24. Проблема: отсутствует связь между клиентами VPN, пинги до сервера ходят исправно, необходимо обеспечить обмен данными между клиентами VPN. Всем откликнувшимся огромное спасибо!

Comment: А порты-то открыты на сервере? Ping - это вообще по другому протоколу ходит.

Comment: На сервере отключены все фаерволлы, поэтому точно ничего не блокируется.

Answer (score 1):

1. Если не ошибаюсь, причина может быть в отключении файервола на сервере, сам натыкался на такой глюк, лучше его включить и правильно настроить.
2. Необходимо определить, строиться ли ВПН канал. Очень помогут в этом tcpdump (он есть не только для unix-ов, для винды тоже в природе существует.
3. Проверить маршруты, т.е. заворачивается ВПН в нужном направлении.Если нужны подробности/советы/помощь - skype:danildan75work, icq:345458854